# How to paste in data.table using a vector as column reference?

Tags: r, data.table

I'm creating a function where I need to paste an text with the values in a random column passed by the user. Suppose I have the following data

```
dt <- data.table(id = letters[1:10], amount = 1:10)
dt
```

What I'm trying to do is given a vector which is column name in the data use it to paste like

```
dt[,id:=paste0('id_',id)]
      id amount
 1: id_a      1
 2: id_b      2
 3: id_c      3
 4: id_d      4
 5: id_e      5
 6: id_f      6
 7: id_g      7
 8: id_h      8
 9: id_i      9
10: id_j     10
```

So if `var` is the vector what I tried is

```
var <- 'id'
dt[,(var):=paste0('id_',eval(var))]
```

but it returns

```
       id amount
 1: id_id      1
 2: id_id      2
 3: id_id      3
 4: id_id      4
 5: id_id      5
 6: id_id      6
 7: id_id      7
 8: id_id      8
 9: id_id      9
10: id_id     10
```

How I can make this be interpreted as a column name in the `data.table`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We could use `get`

```
dt[, (var) := paste0('id_', get(var))]
```

-output

```
> dt
      id amount
 1: id_a      1
 2: id_b      2
 3: id_c      3
 4: id_d      4
 5: id_e      5
 6: id_f      6
 7: id_g      7
 8: id_h      8
 9: id_i      9
10: id_j     10
```

---

Or the standard way is `.SD` or `.SDcols`

```
dt[, (var) := paste0('id_', .SD[[var]])]
```

Comment: Thanks, I tried to do something like `dt[,(var):=paste0('n_',.SD),.SDcols=var]` but it returned a mess, but now I tried `dt[,(var):=Map(paste0,'id_',.SD),.SDcols=var]` and it works ..... a doubt about `get` when you use it inside a `data.table` or `data.frame` the default behavior is to to look at the column names? I tested out of data.table and it says there is no object called `id`

Comment: @R.Cowboy it is because `.SD` is a data.table with a single column.  You need `.SD[[1]]` to extract as a vector.   With a single columns, you can directly do in `.SD` as in my post

Comment: Great answer with `get` or `.SD`, cheers! I cannot find any simpler way than this :)

Answer (score 3):

Maybe you can use `str2lang` within `eval`

```
> dt[, (var) := paste0("id_", eval(str2lang(var)))][]
      id amount
 1: id_a      1
 2: id_b      2
 3: id_c      3
 4: id_d      4
 5: id_e      5
 6: id_f      6
 7: id_g      7
 8: id_h      8
 9: id_i      9
10: id_j     10
```

Comment: thanks, will take a look in this function later

Answer (score 3):

Another option, if you don't want to rewrite the expression:

```
var = 'id'
ex = substitute(
    dt[, var := paste0('id_', var)], 
    list(var = as.name(var))
)
eval(ex)
```

Using `dt` and `var` as names might lead to headaches, as these are names of functions included with R.